# Servlets not being included in the maven project

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, maven, jetty

Can some one help me with this problem. jetty is not able to find my servlet. :(

I am getting the following error-

[image]

This is my directory structure -

[image]

This is my Web.xml  -

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
   <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
   <servlet>
   <servlet-name>loginSer</servlet-name>
   <display-name>loginSer</display-name>
   <description></description>
<servlet-class>launchpad.servlets.loginSer</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>loginSer</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/loginSer</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
 </web-app>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You kept it in wrong directory, it should go under

```
src/main/java
```

not in

```
src/main/resource
```

Maven takes into compilati

**Update**

> when I add it to /src/main/java eclipse cannot import HttpServlet class.

It is because you don't have servlet-api in yoru classpath

add dependency to your POM, replace `${servlet-api-version}` with the appropriate version matching your app environment

```
dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>${servlet-api-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you but when I add it to /src/main/java eclipse cannot import HttpServlet class.

Comment: The /src/main/java folder was created by me. It did not come with default maven-webapp settings. am I supposed to set some permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Your exception reads `com.launchpad.servlets.LoginServlet` but your class is `launchpad.servlets.LoginSer` Are you sure that you're showing the accurate exception and source-code hierarchy?